# Energy lost by CMB since recombination from energy density and scale factor

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background

To calculate the energy lost by CMB since recombination from energy density and scale factor, one should compute today's energy density of CMB * a^-1 or today's energy density of CMB * a^1 with a being the scale factor at recombination?

Comment: The total energy of the CMB doesn't have a standard definition, so it's not clear what you mean by energy lost. Normally we only talk about the energy density.

Answer (score 0):

The energy density of the CMB radiation field is proportional to $T^4$ and hence to $a^{-4}$, where $a$ is the scale factor. If you take a comoving volume, the volume scales as $a^3$ and so the CMB energy within it decreases as $a^{-1}$.

Thus your answer is the present energy density multiplied by $a^{-1}$.

To be clear, this gives you the ratio of how much CMB radiation energy there is in a cube of side $a$ compared with a unit cube $(a=1)$ in the present universe.